# spliting with OR in regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I want to split a math equation with regular expression, but I'm in trouble with one point.

We will take as example this string: `3x^3+2x^2-6x*-3`

After split with some regular expression, I wanna to get this result:

Result that I expect:

```
[0] 3x^3
[1] +2x^2
[2] -6x
[3] *-3
```

I'm trying with this RE: `(?=(\\*-|\\-|\\+|\\*|\\/))`

after `equation.split("(?=(\\*-|\\-|\\+|\\*|\\/))")`

The result is:

```
[0] 3x^3
[1] +2x^2
[2] -6x
[3] *
[4] -3
```

I can't remove that part - `\\-` - because, if my string was: `3x^3+2x^2-6x-3`
I would expect:

```
[0] 3x^3
[1] +2x^2
[2] -6x
[3] -3
```

As you can see, my problem is, how I write a RE that matches `*-` together or matches only `*` or only `-`

My idea is, `(?=(\\*-|\\[^*]-|\\+|\\*|\\/))`, negating the `*` in front of `-`, but this not worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add a negative lookbehind - you only want to split at a hyphen if it is not preceded by a `*`:

```
equation.split("(?=(?<!\\*)-|\\+|\\*|/)")
```